# Folder name for 7" hdpi tablet Android

Tags: java, android, android-resolution

I have Tablet with 7" screen (600×1024) with hdpi (240 dpi classification).

I have created folder `layout-sw600dp`. But it's not working in this resolution tablet.

Its working fine with 7" screen (600×1024) with mdpi (160 dpi classification).

Which folder should I create for 7" (600×1024) tablet which has hdpi (240 dpi classification)?

Answer (score 0):

Make Your Layout like this:

```
res/layout/main_activity.xml           # For handsets (smaller than 600dp available width)
res/layout-sw600dp/main_activity.xml   # For 7” tablets (600dp wide and bigger)
res/layout-sw720dp/main_activity.xml   # For 10” tablets (720dp wide and bigger)
```

For **TAB**:

For example, if your application is only for tablet-style devices with a 600dp smallest available width:

```
<supports-screens
                  android:requiresSmallestWidthDp="600" />
```

[image]

I have **Tablet with 7" screen (600×1024) with hdpi (240 dpi classification)** which is comes under the **Normal Screen** see my screen shot.**Its working fine with 7" screen (600×1024) with mdpi (160 dpi classification)** which is comes under the **large screen**.

[**For Tablet**](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#DeclaringTabletLayouts) .

**MULTIPLE SCREENS:**

For example, the following is a list of resource directories in an application that provides different layout designs for different screen sizes and different bitmap drawables for medium, high, and extra high density screens.

```
res/layout/my_layout.xml             // layout for normal screen size ("default")
res/layout-small/my_layout.xml       // layout for small screen size
res/layout-large/my_layout.xml       // layout for large screen size
res/layout-xlarge/my_layout.xml      // layout for extra large screen size
res/layout-xlarge-land/my_layout.xml // layout for extra large in landscape orientation

res/drawable-mdpi/my_icon.png        // bitmap for medium density
res/drawable-hdpi/my_icon.png        // bitmap for high density
res/drawable-xhdpi/my_icon.png       // bitmap for extra high density
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: res/layout-sw600dp/main_activity.xml   # For 7” tablets (600dp wide and bigger)
res/layout-sw720dp/main_activity.xml I have tried with both the folder but not working.

Comment: Because I have Tablet with 7" screen (600×1024) with hdpi (240 dpi classification) which is comes under the Normal Screen see my screen shot.Its working fine with 7" screen (600×1024) with mdpi (160 dpi classification) which is comes under the large screen. Please check it with my screen shot.

Comment: what should be image size for normal Screen?

Comment: res/drawable-mdpi/my_icon.png        // bitmap for medium density
res/drawable-hdpi/my_icon.png        // bitmap for high density
res/drawable-xhdpi/my_icon.png       // bitmap for extra high density Check my edited answer it depends upon the density.

Answer (score 0):

It depends from the Android API version you're building against, like mentioned [here](http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes.html):

> ... However, this won't work well on pre-3.2 devices, because they
>   don't recognize sw600dp as a size qualifier, so you still have to use
>   the large qualifier as well. So, you should have a file named
>   res/layout-large/main.xml which is identical to
>   res/layout-sw600dp/main.xml. In the next section you'll see a
>   technique that allows you to avoid duplicating the layout files this
>   way.

You should also take a look here:

[Preparing for Handsets](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/09/preparing-for-handsets.html)

and

[New Tools For Managing Screen Sizes](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/07/new-tools-for-managing-screen-sizes.html)

Comment: android os is 4.1.2 so it can recognize sw600

Answer (score 0):

In android, we use resolution in `dp` to measure the screen size, not resolution in `px`.
Both of your two tablets have the same resolution in `px`, but their resolution in `dp` are quite different.

1. 600 X 1024px with mdpi  =  600 * 1024 dp
2. 600 X 1024px with hdpi  =  400 * 682 dp

You use `sw600dp` as the qualifier for tablet, which will effect the first device but not the second one.

In fact, the second device(400 * 682dp), is much more like a handset rather than a tablet, it should not use the layout for tablet.