# Targeting multiple screen sizes in android...How to?

Tags: android

I am creating layouts for targeting my application for all screen sizes and densities (including tablets 7,9.1 and 10 inches). I have a few queries for which I haven't been able to understand well even though after reading the documentation. Currently, I have made four layouts namely **layout-large**,**normal**,**small**,**-sw320dp** and **-sw480dp**. I am confused about images densities.

I am referring to the image that android provides by default (`ic_launcher.png` under `drawable-hdpi`, `drawable-ldpi`, `drawable-mdpi`, `drawable-xhdpi` and `drawable-xxhdpi`.) I have made a sample layout taken a image view and given src as **ic_launcher.png**. However, this image is not displayed on any device or emulator.

1. Do I need to specify different sized images? If so, in which folders? Because layouts for larger screens should take larger images.
2. Do `hdpi`, `ldpi`, and `mdpi` imply similar sized images with different density or images with different sizes only?
3. Also in case of layout for larger screen, should I refer to **drawables** for large sized images (if I am taking small, medium, large images), or will Android take it from `drawable-hdpi`?

Comment: Please try to frame your question in such a way that some one will actually want to solve it. you may seem that this is a rude remark but proper formatting will help you get better answers for your problems. :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17585605/1835764

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html check this

Comment: http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes.html this also can help you

Comment: But why is it not showing the image on any of the devices or emulator if android takes the image at runtime.Any of the devices will still come under a category as mentioned above

Comment: in think the problem is in your xml file. not in the folder. make textview instead of imageview to check whether it is working or not!!!

Comment: Nirmal i added a text view as well and i have named them differently like for small screen textview is named as small and so forth that works perfectly however only the problem comes in case of image.Only image is not displayed it shows as blank

Comment: can you see an image in normal screen? have you tested all the screen size?

Comment: No Nirmal though for normal screen text that i have mentioned as normal is displayed however the image is not displayed

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33261/discussion-between-nirmal-and-joyson)

Answer (score 0):

You only need to put the images in the right folder: using `hdpi` + `mdpi` + `xhdpi` + `xxhdpi`

`ldpi` is only **1%** of the android devices and you should not make them.

you also can create different layouts for larger screens

[read here for more info](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)