# Designing Android apps for tablets

Tags: android, google-play, android-manifest, tablet

In the Play developer console it says:

> Your APK does not seem to be designed for tablets

But I have added layouts to *layout-sw600dp*, *layout-sw600dp-land*, *layout-sw720dp* and *layout-sw720dp-land* folders. The complete manifest (as it is):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.technicosa.unjumble"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="9"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

<supports-screens
    android:anyDensity="true"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:resizeable="true"
    android:smallScreens="true"
    android:xlargeScreens="true" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.Sherlock.Light.DarkActionBar" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.technicosa.unjumble.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.technicosa.unjumble.UserSettingsActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_user_settings" >
    </activity>
</application>
```

The app runs perfectly  on both Nexus 7 and Nexus 10 in the emulator. Also in the developer console under optimization tips it says:

> **Your Production APK needs to meet the following criteria:** Uses available screen space on 10-inch tablets

A screenshot of my app:

[image]

While the app seems to run on tablets (I have tested only on emulator), what must be done to fulfill the Play criteria?

Comment: You should remove `android:resizeable="true"` as it is deprecated and should not be used.  also did you pull out any uses-features?

Comment: u need use android:layout_weigth in xml files..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17585605/1835764

Comment: You should set android:normalScreens="false" and android:smallScreens="false"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Replacing folders layout-sw600dp, layout-sw600dp-land, layout-sw720dp and layout-sw720dp-land with layout-xlarge, layout-xlarge-land added a new message: "your apk does not seem to be designed for tablets."

Solved the problem after what's stated [here](http://developer.android.com/distribute/googleplay/quality/tablet.html#use-extra-space).

> **Take advantage of extra screen area available on tablets**
>
> - Look for opportunities to include additional content or use an alternative treatment of existing content.
> - Use multi-pane layouts on tablet screens to combine single views into a compound view. This lets you use the additional screen area more efficiently and makes it easier for users to navigate your app.

The problem was really the white space and had nothing to do with the xmls.

I managed to make the message for 7i tabs go away by rearranging the layouts to cover the screen and not leave too much white space. But not for the 10i tablets as the area is too big and my app has very less content. I must consider additional content.

Comment: Hi arjun! Is there any other methods? or otherwise I have to edit everything again.. :(

Comment: As some of the other answers suggest, try uploading a better screenshot.

Comment: I've designed my game to fit any screen with the same width:height ratio. It's nice they have this Best Practices docs, but I don't have the time to read, and implement all this stuff.

Answer (score 34):

I don't believe that this is a completely automated process. In other words, I think there is someone in Google looking at screen shots from your app making a qualitative judgement (probably an intern). This is my reasoning for arriving at that conclusion:

I have three versions of my app (Irish, UK and USA). They are basically the same with different text. The Irish version was released first and initially I encountered that message. I had implemented the manifest (like yours) and had one or two xml files in  layout-sw600dp and layout-sw600dp-land and I couldn't see the cause of the problem. I uploaded a new apk with new screen shots (no xml or manifest changes) and the problem went away. Here is the current status of the Irish app:[image]
.

Next I implemented the UK version. It displayed "when you did it" as 12th June, the date the APK was uploaded. So at least there is a semblance of consistency in the review process.

Finally - the US version. To reiterate, this is basically the same app with the same xml as the Irish and UK versions and this is my current message:

[image]

Now it is quite possible that Google have written some code to look for xmls for large tablets. But if they had, I think my other APKs would be showing that error as well. Therefore, I think that the review process is partly manual.

So my conclusion - a quantitative approach may help (a few more xmls in sw600dp and sw720dp) but don't neglect the qualitative stuff (choose screen shots that don't display empty space !).

**Update: re. the "Designed for Phones" message - December 2013**

Since I wrote the above Google have introduced the dreaded "Designed for Phones" tagline and "Design your app for tablets" optimisation tips. This appears to be largely based on an automated scan of the apk when you upload it (probably the xml), so the process now seems to be more automated than was previously the case. Here are some points I have discovered which may help others:

1) I was unhappy that Google had designated one of my apps as "designed for phones" and I emailed them and they then removed this designation.

2) On a different app, I was getting the "design your app for 7" tablets" optimisation tip. I added one fragment to my tablet xml in sw600dp like this:

```
       <FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/SideTab1"
    android:name="SideTab1"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    />
```

and this **did not** remove the optimisation tip.

3)However when I made the same change to a second xml in sw600dp then the "design your app for 7" tablets" optimisation tip was replaced by "Your layout should make use of the available space on 10-inch tablets". **More importantly, the "designed for phones" designation has now disappeared.**

4) Obviously my next step is to make similiar changes in sw720dp.

Things seem to have changed again now (e.g. Google seem to now have removed the "designed for phones" designation in the country in which I am currently residing, and they seem to have relaxed some of their "rules" regarding the "design your app for tablets" message). Apparently, I am now doing "pretty well", which is reassuring news !

Comment: Some of my screenshots do have empty space: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.technicosa.unjumble

Comment: What do you mean by a few more xmls?

Comment: Well in June, two xmls in each of sw600dp and sw600dp-land was sufficient to make the message disappear for both 7" and 10" tablets. That may have changed now. Of course they could now be running the apks (or some of them) but I have no proof of this at the moment.

Comment: Imagine that - an intern in the box, just like Maelzel's chess player :-)  For full confirmation of your theory, try leaving a message with a job offer and a phone number on your screenshots, and see if you get any calls *before* the app goes live.  Then again, they're working for Google, so why would they call anyone else?

Comment: Hi, I'm having the same problem. How did you email Google to complain about the issue? My app is clearly designed for tablets but Google Play doesn't recognise that. So I looked around but cannot find any way to contact someone at Google to address the issue. Thanks!

Comment: Hi Henry, things seem to be changing quite fast (e.g. Google seem to now have removed the "designed for phones" designation in the country in which I am currently residing, and they seem to have relaxed some of their "rules" regarding the "design your app for tablets" message). Apparently, I am now doing "pretty well", so do  check your developer console first. That email address is googleplay-developer-support@google.com

Answer (score 7):

Same in my case like @Wytas and @blackdigger, images were problem too. So I generate the images from http://developer.android.com/distribute/promote/device-art.html then warning message gone.

Comment: Wow, this actually helped. I tried a second 10" screenshot, but that didn't help. Then I tried using the same screen shot via the generator as you said and the warning message about the APK was gone.

Comment: They've caught onto you: that page now says, "Note: Do not use graphics created here in your 1024x500 feature image or screenshots for your Google Play app listing."

Answer (score 5):

I was able to solve it by uploading another screenshot for 10-inch tablet which contains less white space than previous my screenshot.

Comment: It's not the screenshots because I've got the message even before uploading them.

Answer (score 5):

I had "*Your layout should make use of the available space on tablets*"
message after uploading first draft of the new application. I've spend an hour trying to change layout of my single activity, tried different folder names, even removed all activities with their layouts - nothing helped.
I can confirm @Wytas answer. My problem was that for a draft new app I've uploaded screenshot and promo images which were **completely black stub images** (meant to be updated later). Once I **changed screenshots & promo images** to the ones taken from another app (which didn't have that warning message in developer console) the message is gone! I believe Google Play just *analyzes screenshots* (and maybe promo images) automatically, looking for patches of the uniform color and considers it as bad "layout".

Answer (score 2):

I think you may have problem with layout folders  layout-sw600dp, layout-sw600dp-land, layout-sw720dp and layout-sw720dp-land

Try layout folders  like layout-xlarge, layout-xlarge-land and  put your dimens at values-sw600dp and  values-sw720dp

And also have a look at the below link

http://developer.android.com/distribute/googleplay/quality/tablet.html

Comment: Will layout-xlarge support both 7i and 10i tablets?

Comment: layout-large etc...is already deprecated and leads into "APK does not seem to be designed for 7-inch tablets" error

Answer (score 2):

It seems all to be about screenshots! I have quoted this from google play listing store section in google play console *24/09/2015* :

> **Screenshots: ***
>
> Default – Arabic – ar JPEG or 24-bit PNG (no alpha). Min length for
>   any side: 320px. Max length for any side: 3840px.
>
> At least 2 screenshots are required overall. Max 8 screenshots per
>   type. Drag to reorder or to move between types.
>
> For your app to be showcased in the 'Designed for tablets' list in the
>   Play Store, you need to upload at least one 7-inch and one 10-inch
>   screenshot. If you previously uploaded screenshots, make sure to move
>   them into the right area below.

I uploaded new screenshots, the problem was solved!

Actually depending on the screenshots is more logical than depending on analysing the APK. Since some apps has not lots of contents to show!

**Happy Androiding!**

Answer (score 1):

After having this same problem and foraging through several forums, what worked for me was changing the targetSDKVersion in the manifest to 11.
You can change either minSDKVersion OR targetSDKVersion, as long as one of them is at 11.
Also if you use any plugins (like Google Play Services), there's a chance they included their own manifest file somewhere, so make sure ALL the manifest have the same SDK values or your build will not run.

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure that folder `layout-sw600dp`, `layout-sw600dp-land`, `layout-sw720dp` and `layout-sw720dp-land` are well written, i think that it is not necessary to write this part of code:

```
<supports-screens android:resizeable="true"
      android:smallScreens="true"
      android:normalScreens="true"
      android:largeScreens="true"
      android:xlargeScreens="true"
      android:anyDensity="true" />
```

If you plan to target all Android devices. Try it!

Then check if you already posted some screeshot for 10" Tablets and 7" Tablets in their relative section. I had this warning until i posted some screenshots.

Comment: The screenshots are there. The concern is "making use of space on 10i tablets."

Answer (score 0):

I read somewhere on the play store page that it needs some screenshots for 7" and 10" tablets in order to be featured as "for tablets", whether there is a specific layout for it or not.

Comment: I have uploaded the screenshots.

Answer (score 0):

Add in file build.grandle

```
 compile ‘com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.+’
```

where 19 - it's `compileSdkVersion`

Comment: The link is broken

Answer (score 0):

On the link https://developer.android.com/distribute/marketing-tools/device-art-generator they have mentioned a note

> Do not use graphics created here in your feature image or screenshots for your Google Play store listing, using the screenshot alone without framing is recommended. See the Google Play graphics guidelines.

I have tried updating screenshot without device frame and the warning is gone.

Comment: Google itself puts screenshots with device frame https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.magazines&hl=en

Comment: @ArjunU. I am talking about the warning. It disappeared in my case.