# How do you fix the 10 inch tablet compatibility in google play

Tags: android, android-layout, google-play, publish, tablet

I have published an app in google play but i can't make it compatible with tablets .
The google play says that my app needs to "Use available screen space on 10-inch tablets".
I created defferent layouts for tablets (layout-sw600 and layout-sw720) but the problem remains .
What else do i need to fix ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Designing android apps for tablets](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17938163/designing-android-apps-for-tablets)

Answer (score 0):

Try to upload another screenshot with less white space in it.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/19478350/1683803