# Uploading app to playstore: tablet compatibility error!! : android

Tags: android, uploading

I am trying to upload my first app to play store. I have uploaded my apk to console and drafted it. Then there is a orange bulb saying,**Your APK is designed for tablets. For your app to be showcased in the 'Designed for tablets' list in the Play Store, you need to upload at least one 7-inch or 10-inch tablet screenshot for the Store listing.** But when I added a screenshot for 7" tablet it shows like **You uploaded screenshots for 7-inch tablets, but your APK does not seem to be designed for 7-inch tablets.** 
So what should I need to make it accepted. Actually my app works well with tablets.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Answered already here: [Designing Android apps for tablets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17938163/designing-android-apps-for-tablets)

http://developer.android.com/distribute/googleplay/quality/tablet.html#use-extra-space

> Take advantage of extra screen area available on tablets
>
> Look for opportunities to include additional content or use an
>   alternative treatment of existing content.
>
> Use multi-pane layouts on tablet screens to combine single views into
>   a compound view. This lets you use the additional screen area more
>   efficiently and makes it easier for users to navigate your app.

Comment: So you say its the same issue? I have to edit my layouts to have less white spaces? I have a lot to go then. Is there any other methods?

Comment: Not just whitespace, but changing your layout on larger screens.

Comment: I have just two three buttons on some of my screens. So I think its not so good even if I change the layout. correct?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure, that you don't declare your tablet layouts in res/layout-large folder (deprecated), use `layout-sw600dp` instead.

This solved the same problem for me recently.

Comment: Oh! So do I need to remove layout-large and replace it with layout-sw600dp ?? I have both folders for now!

Comment: I am not sure about using layout-large and layout-sw600dp simultaneously...isn't it generating conflicts for some specific devices, which are 'large' and also are at least 600dp wide? I would use only large or only sw600dp identifier.