# Make Android app show up as designed for tablets

Tags: android, cordova, google-play

I have a cordova app on the PlayStore but in the optimization tips it's showing that the app is not designed for tablets. I've looked around and changed the `<supports-screens>` tag but it's still not working and I'm still getting the optimization tip.

Here's the manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest android:versionCode="11"    
                    android:versionName="$BundleVersion$" 
                    package="$AppIdentifier$" 
                    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
                    android:hardwareAccelerated="$AndroidHardwareAcceleration$"
                    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
        <supports-screens
                android:largeScreens="true"
                android:normalScreens="true"
                android:smallScreens="true"
                android:xlargeScreens="true"
                android:resizeable="true"
                android:anyDensity="true"
                />

        <application android:label="@string/app_name" 
                                 android:icon="@drawable/icon" 
                                 android:hardwareAccelerated="$AndroidHardwareAcceleration$">
                <activity android:label="@string/app_name" 
                    android:name=".TelerikCallbackActivity"
                    android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale"
                    android:launchMode="standard"
                                    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar" >
                        <intent-filter>
                                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                        </intent-filter>
                </activity>
        </application>
        <uses-sdk android:targetSdkVersion="14" />
</manifest>
```

And here's the config file:

```
<cordova>

    <content src="index.html" />

    <preference name="useBrowserHistory" value="true" />
    <preference name="exit-on-suspend" value="false" />
    <preference name="fullscreen" value="true" />
    <preference name="permissions" value="none"/>

    <plugins>
        <plugin name="App" value="org.apache.cordova.App"/>
        <plugin name="Device" value="org.apache.cordova.Device"/>
    </plugins>
</cordova>
```

What do I need to do to make the app available for tablets?

Comment: Related/possible dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17938163/designing-android-apps-for-tablets

Comment: @hichris123: it's related but nothing there helped me. Still looking for a code-based answer.

Comment: I'm quite sure you just need to add some resources for large screens, like layout-large/home.xml to show you actually did something for tablets, in the manifest you just say that you are ok with your app running on tablets.

Answer (score 3):

What you need is not 'a code-based answer'.

Google Play will review your uploaded information to judge if app is also for tablets.

That should include things below.

(1) App with tablets splash screen

(2) App with tablets icon

(3) Configuration for tablets screen. (You have set it according to your question)

(4) Information for tablets. (screenshot, propaganda images etc.)

Comment: 1) My app works in phonegap; no splashscreen, 2) I've got all the icon size loaded, 3) I think I'm good with that (see question code), 4) I've got all the info uploaded.

Comment: Do you have a different layout for tablets? You cant just say, 'yes this is for tablets' without doing anything to utilize the much larger screen.

Comment: @Lukos Yes, a responsive design for tablet is also necessary.