# Problems making my Application show as desgined for tablets

Tags: android, google-play, drawable

I have seen this topic a lot at stack overflow, have test a lot of things this threads recommended but I can't make my application to show under the tablet category.

The warning that shows below optimization tips is: Your APK should include custom drawables assets for common tablet screen densities.

I have added icons for m,l,h,x and xx densitives below mimmap-xxx folders. I have added a dummy picture under drawable-xxxx with differnt denstities to test. I have added minsdk to be at 11. Nothing, the warning doesn't want to go away.

Could anyone give any other tip or can see something I have missed?

Cheers.

Comment: Is your apk in alpha/beta?

Comment: No, it is not. It is on production. By the way is there any way to test this kind of things without having to upload the apk to google play? It is a bit of a nightmare when things do not go well to have to compile-upload a lot of times and more in your production channel :(.

Comment: The only other thing that I do, that you haven't already done, is add sw600dp drawables (I'm guessing you've already added screenshots for 7-inch and 10-inch screens). Also, I don't think there is any other way other than uploading a new apk to production every time.

Comment: Yes I added screenshots for the 7 and 10-inch screens. I don't have a sw600dp drawables, but I think that it is not needed if you have drawables in xhdpi and xxhdpi. The only think I don't know if when the message is updated. Is it updated as soon as you publish the new app? Or does it go away after it has been live?

Comment: This answer might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17938163/designing-android-apps-for-tablets

Answer (score 1):

You should check your manifest file, I had some trouble with it because I asked some permissions which may only be available on a smartphone - and not tablet.

For example, if you want a phone user to be able to call from your app, you must include the permission below but put the required attribute to false because the user is able to use your app without that functionality:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" android:required="false"/>
```

You should not find the app in the playstore if you don't put the required attribute to false with a tablet because most of them are unable to call.

Comment: Good point, but this is not the reason. The only features I use are android.hardware.screen.PORTRAIT
android.hardware.TOUCHSCREEN
android.hardware.WIFI. All are available on phones and tablets.
And this regular permissions:
android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE
android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE
android.permission.INTERNET
android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE

Comment: With which tablets did you try to find your app?

Comment: Did you check the point 10 of the page : https://developer.android.com/distribute/essentials/quality/tablets.html ? They say "For apps targeting minSdkVersion value less than 13, a <supports-screens> element must be declared with both android:largeScreens="true" and android:xlargeScreens="true"."

Comment: I have the support-screen tag in my android manifest. Beside your options I set small,normal to true and anyDestity to true too.

Comment: your weird answer doesn't make sense, Google Console says about **drawables** (so it's sure not about call permission): **Your APK should include custom drawables assets for common tablet screen densities.**

Answer (score 0):

After some researching and tests I managed to upload an app without that warning. The only thing I did was set minsdk to 11 and add

```
<supports-screens 
  android:smallScreens="true"
  android:normalScreens="true"
  android:largeScreens="true"
  android:xlargeScreens="true"
  android:anyDensity="true" />
```

to the manifest. This makes your as designed for tables, at least for my app.

Note: This did not remove the message in another app I updated, but it did when I uploaded it as a new one.

Cheers.