# how to get google play to mark unity game as designed for tablets?

Tags: android, google-play, unity-game-engine, tablet

i'm trying to publish my unity game on google play and i cant find an answer to this error anywhere. when i upload a 10" screenshot google play says "You uploaded screenshots for 10-inch tablets, but your APK does not seem to be designed for 10-inch tablets." when i click learn more it says "Your APK should include custom drawables assets for common tablet screen densities."

there may be a lot of answers to similar questions but i haven't been able to find an answer for the error "Your APK should include custom drawables assets for common tablet screen densities." i could be wrong but i was under the impression Unity took care of this aspect.

What do i need to do differently to fix this issue so my games is listed as "designed for tablets"? my game works and can be download on tablets... but says its not designed for them?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Designing Android apps for tablets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17938163/designing-android-apps-for-tablets)

Comment: i have checked that and many other similar posts and i cant find one about the error i'm having.

Comment: What's your unity version?

Comment: 2017.3.0f3 sorry there was no option for 2017 in the tags.

Comment: Tag-wise, the unity tags are all synonyms anyway. Per your problem, have you tried the things listed in the possible dup target? Have you included the 10 inch screen in your resolution settings (Edit -> Project Settings -> Player)?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken you need to provide a '.aar' file in your assets folder that has the different textures for different screen densities. I do not believe Unity handles this for you. See here:
https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/AndroidAARPlugins.html

Comment: I guess i have a lot of learning and research to do on this one but thank you very much for helping me find a direction to pursue.

Comment: Any luck with solving that? I have just realized my apps that were previously fine also face the same issue (I am  using 2017.3)

Answer (score 3):

I solved this problem with just simple trick.
You can just check on "Include android banner" option in player setting for android build and select any image for android banner. Then unity will automatically generate res/drawable-xhdpi folder with that banner image included.

You have to just check this option on and select any image you want
[here is example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vm3tX.png)

Comment: Which version of Unity are you using? I don't have that option in 2019.1.8f1.

Comment: Under the "Icon" section in "Player Settings", if yo try to add multiple resolution icons then the xhdpi is created and the "Optimisation tip" in google play disappears. Adding the android banner is easier for sure

Comment: nice and simple solution!

Answer (score 0):

I was running into this same issue and found a solution that worked for me. Unity apparently fails to create a folder required to correctly process the APK, namely a 'drawable-xhdpi' folder that's supposed to contain a 320px by 180px image inside of the res/ folder.

Found this answer because I happen to be working on two apps at the same time — the first app was exporting without any issues, whereas the second app encountered the problem you've described.

Using Unity 2018.3.0f2, I exported the first app and the second app using Gradle via the Build Settings dialogue.

Here's a screenshot of the res/ folder from the first (working) app:

[Image of res/ folder from project with all necessary folders](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zNEMU.png)

Here's a screenshot of the res/ folder from the second (broken) app:

[Image of res/ folder from project missing one crucial folder, drawable-xhdpi](https://i.stack.imgur.com/94GbE.png)

Notice how the 2nd app is missing the 'drawable-xhdpi' folder.

So I fixed this by taking the 2nd app exported project into Android Studio, manually adding the missing folder and image asset, then exporting as normal. After uploading to the Google Play Developer Console, voila! No error.

Hope this helps :-)