# Android App for Tablet

Tags: android

My App show device is not supported on play store when i install app on Samsung GT-P3113 Tablet. Why?
App Manifest file

```
 <supports-screens
    android:anyDensity="true"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:resizeable="true"
    android:smallScreens="true"
    android:xlargeScreens="true" />

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

<permission
    android:name="com.parkhya.treebidsale.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />
<permission
    android:name="com.parkhya.treebidsale.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-permission android:name="com.parkhya.treebidsale.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"
    android:required="false" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"
    android:required="false" />

<uses-feature
    android:name="android:hardware.camera"
    android:required="false" />
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus"
    android:required="false" />
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.LOCATION"
    android:required="false" />
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.location.GPS"
    android:required="false" />
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.screen.PORTRAIT"
    android:required="false" />
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.TELEPHONY"
    android:required="false" />
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.TOUCHSCREEN"
    android:required="false" />

<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"
    android:required="false" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission
    android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"
    android:required="false" />
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"
    android:required="false" />
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"
    android:required="false" />
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS"
    android:required="false" />
```

I also try app with some different change in manifest file but same message show.
On Play Store Account below msg show in our app 
Your Production APK needs to meet the following criteria:
Any required hardware features are normally available on tablets. Learn more

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17585605/1835764

Comment: duplicate of [Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11691775/why-my-app-is-not-showing-up-on-tablets-in-google-play)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android is generally case-sensitive. Do not invent your own rules for case.

Similarly, do not invent your own rules for what attributes are available on what elements.

Specifically (with links to the related documentation):

- [`<uses-permission>` does not support `android:required`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-permission-element.html)
- [All `<uses-feature>` names are lowercase](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element.html#features-reference)

Hence, I would imagine that tablets sans telephony will not support your app because you are trying to control `android.hardware.TELEPHONY`, not `android.hardware.telephony`.