# Couldn't make a Tablet only app

Tags: android, android-layout

I have referred stack overflow and used "Support screens" attribute in manifest file like this:

```
<supports-screens android:smallScreens="false"
                      android:normalScreens="false"
                      android:largeScreens="false"
                      android:xlargeScreens="true"
                      android:requiresSmallestWidthDp="600" />

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="14"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
```

But still I am able to install it in any type of screens. Have tried in sony tipo and I could install it. Whats wrong here?

Comment: Actually following only helps you to filter your application in android market only.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17585605/1835764

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You should allow large screens, since this applies for 7" tablets
2. You can't filter the app from being installed on phones (via Eclipse, or if it's downloaded from an external source). This setting will restrict the app from being downloaded on phones from the Google Play Market.

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 1):

Installing an apk is always possible as far as I know. In the Play Store the app would'nt be diplayed in any list of apps if the requirements aren't fullfilled.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm not mistaken you could also use:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/compatible-screens-element.html

```
<compatible-screens>
```

That should actually limit the devices through the Play Store as the warning says:

```
Caution: Normally, you should not use this manifest element. 
Using this element can dramatically reduce the potential 
user base for your application, by not allowing users to 
install your application if they have a device with a screen 
configuration that you have not listed. 
You should use it only as a last resort, when the application 
absolutely does not work with specific screen configurations.
```

But be careful and read the documentation and the warnings.

Also one way is to actually enable only tablets in the devices filter 
when you are publishing your app (in the Google Play Developer Console, on the web).