# Tablet not enabled on Play store

Tags: android, google-play

I've searched around and read all the related docs on google play, I'm just not getting how to "enable" tablets for my app. I have the resources for all the devices I want to support, which is basically everything from API 8+

[image: resource folders]

I also don't require features that tablets may not have and added everything to supports-screens:

[image: manifest]

Play store says my APK is compatible with every tablet I searched for:

[image: devices]

After all this, Google Play still says I'm missing something:

[image: playview]

If anyone knows how to get this working, please share, thanks.

Similar links:
[Tablet only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19241201/couldnt-make-a-tablet-only-app/) | [7 inch tablet folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17585576/folder-name-for-7-hdpi-tablet-android/)

**EDIT**

I'm still a bit stumped on this, but I did email google and today I noticed that in the store, all my devices now show as compatible; however, in the developer console, I still see the "lightbulb" hint.

[image: Compatible Devices in Store]

Comment: Please read the link “What you need to fix”

Comment: I did that and you'll find that the items pictured are what they show in that page